# Javascript script for identifying multiple days of the week

Tags: javascript, days

I am not a javascript coder, but I need to modify this code so that I can have a status bar shown for multiple times during the week.  How can I add to this statement to cover another day of the week or other times on Sunday?  I need to have the bar show up Sunday from 5pm to 7pm and Thursday between 7p and 9p.  Just wondered how I could modify this to work.  Can someone help?

```
var d = new Date();
var Day = d.getDay();
var Time = d.getHours();
    if (d.getDay() == 0 && d.getHours() >= 9 && d.getHours() <= 12) {
      jQuery(".streaming").show();
    } else {
      jQuery(".streaming").hide();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you must understand how the Date's instance methods that you are using works. You can try it here [getDay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay), and here [getHours](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours).

So, you code goes to something like:

```
var date = new Date();
var day = date.getDay();
var hour = date.getHours();

if ((day == 0 && hour >= 17 && hour <= 19) ||
    (day == 5 && hour >= 19 && hour <= 21)) {
    jQuery(".streaming").show();
} else {
    jQuery(".streaming").hide();
}
```

You should take a look at the [OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR) (||) operator in JavaScript too.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help.  Based on your help I have modified it and also added a specific minute as well.  Is this a proper way to do this or should I not be using get.Minutes?

```
var date = new Date();
var day = date.getDay();
var hour = date.getHours();
var minute = date.getMinutes();

if ((day == 0 && hour >= 08  && minute >= 50 && hour <= 12) ||
    (day == 0 && hour >= 16  && minute >= 50 && hour <= 19) ||
    (day == 5 && hour >= 18  && minute >= 50 && hour <= 21)) {
    jQuery(".streaming").show();
} else {
    jQuery(".streaming").hide();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you to refactor like this

```
if (showForDay(d)) {
  jQuery(".streaming").show();
} else {
  jQuery(".streaming").hide();
}

function showForDay(d){
  // put all your conditions here
  if (d.getDay() == 0 && d.getHours() >= 9 && d.getHours() <= 12) return true
  if (d.getDay() == 0 && d.getHours() >= 12 && d.getHours() <= 14) return true
  ...
  return false // will be hidden
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer to OP's question.

Comment: Sorry but this is answer to OP's question. It gives an easy way how to write as many condition as needed and on the top of that it is making the code cleaner. For better clarity I added another condition...